# how we get uber api results in us dollar currency code with Indian account

Tags: uber-api

I have Indian uber developer account , so its give me results in INR currency _code  , but I want results in us dollar , anybody tell me how it is possible.

```
    {
  "prices": [
    {
      "localized_display_name": "uberGO",
      "distance": 0,
      "display_name": "uberGO",
      "product_id": "40269682-90dc-4d18-8c38-5b4035e35296",
      "high_estimate": 40,
      "surge_multiplier": 1,
      "minimum": 40,
      "low_estimate": 40,
      "duration": 0,
      "estimate": "₹ 40",
      "currency_code": "INR"
    },
    {
      "localized_display_name": "uberX",
      "distance": 0,
      "display_name": "uberX",
      "product_id": "8e1107eb-82f3-4ed4-9969-e6c7c73d8c86",
      "high_estimate": 50,
      "surge_multiplier": 1,
      "minimum": 50,
      "low_estimate": 50,
      "duration": 0,
      "estimate": "₹ 50",
      "currency_code": "INR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this link should help: https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/guides/localization

"Currency: Currency is rendered in the local currency of a given latitude & longitude pair. A fare estimate in San Francisco will be given in USD, while a fare estimate in Paris will be displayed in EUR. We also provide the ISO 4217 currency code for your own conversions."

Cheers.